# create new dataframe from pandas value counts

Tags: python, pandas

So I have something like this:

```
df.groupby('user_id').sentiment.value_counts()
```

Which gives me something like:

[image]

Is there anyway I can make a new dataframe that will go like:

[image]

I wanna be able to do this so I can perform some fancy operations with the numbers like get percentages and stuff.

Comment: `df.groupby('user_id').sentiment.value_counts().unstack('sentiment').reset_index()`?

Comment: @ansev woah that's pretty amazing, thanks so much! want to put it as an answer so i can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df.groupby('user_id').sentiment.value_counts().unstack('sentiment').reset_index()
```